# Getting JSON in " Android Asynchronous Http Client Library "

Tags: android, json, asynchronous

I recently moved to `Android Asynchronous Http Client Library` for faster data moving.

I want to move my codes from the old state and a new state.. Here's how I used to get The data :

```
public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputStream isr = null;
            String result = "";
            String url;
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpost;
            HttpResponse resposne;
            HttpEntity entity;
            BufferedReader reader;
            StringBuilder sb;
            String line = null;

            try {
                url = "Secret";
                httpost = new HttpPost(url);
                resposne = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                entity = resposne.getEntity();
                isr = entity.getContent();
                reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(isr, "UTF-8"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                isr.close();
                result = sb.toString();

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    //filldatabase///
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

And now what shall I do so I can use the library?? Thank you!

Comment: Here you go: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ Just read the documentation

Comment: @Lefteris Dude I saw the documentation.. but nothing on JSON.. can you help me please?

Comment: Dude, [here you go](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/sample/JsonSample.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the example in the documentation:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://your/url/here/", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(response);
        for(int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
            // do your things...
        }
    }
});
```

You don't need an AsyncTask anymore, place the code to replace `new loadSomeStuff().start()` and remove the `loadSomeStuff` class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be careful to use this library, because you can not use it in the AsyncTask. I guess that it has already using the thread.
2. If there's nothing on JSON, that might because the data haven't return yet. Therefore, you have to wait util the data return before you do the parsing job.

---

I have experiences of using this library. And I think this library is appropriate to some cases that callbacks are not that important. For example, you don't have to wait for data return and parse it.

Maybe you can try this(Not recommended):

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("url", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    //Check the data return
    while(response.length==0)
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);// Waiting for data return
    }
    //Parsing data
    JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); ++i) {
        JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
        ...
    }
}
```

});

---

Here are some advices for your old codes :)
*Separate the http post and the JSON. And put both of them in a class. **Doing this could make your code more briefly and also reusable.** Here's what I mean:

```
public class Util {

public String doPost() {
    InputStream isr = null;
    String result = "";
    String url;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost;
    HttpResponse resposne;
    HttpEntity entity;
    BufferedReader reader;
    StringBuilder sb;
    String line = null;

    try {
           url = "Secret";
           httpost = new HttpPost(url);
           resposne = httpclient.execute(httpost);
           entity = resposne.getEntity();
           isr = entity.getContent();
           reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(isr, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    isr.close();
                    result = sb.toString();

                    //Remove JSON
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public parsindData(String result)
{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //filldatabase///
}
```

}

**Use them as Object:**

//AsyncTask doInBackground

```
Util util=new Util();
String getCallBack=util.doPost();
if(getCallBack.length!=0)
{
    util.parsingData(getCallBack);
}
```